# Why would you not accept a free great person?

Tags: civilization-6

I have seen players on Twitch choose to not accept a great person they have attracted.

What might be a reason to do this?

Comment: Maybe they don't feel like having the person around because they don't have anywhere to put their great works, and aren't planning on building any places for them?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Great Persons aren't actually free, but are purchased using Great Person Points (GPP). GPP act just like any other currency, and there's a different kind for every type of great person (i.e. great scientist points, great artist points, et cetera).

Once you've acquired enough GPP of a certain type you'll be prompted by the game to purchase a great person. If you buy it then all the GPP of the relevant type get deducted from your total (usually putting you back to 0), and the next great person of that type becomes available. If you pass, though, it's cost is reduced for every other civilization and you'll keep all your GPP. Once another Civilization buys the great person a new one becomes available for purchase, who you'll likely be able to buy with all those GPP you saved up from not buying the last one.

So, the reason you'd skip out on getting a great person would be because you don't actually want that great person, and would rather save up your GPP for the next one that shows up. The reason you might not want a specific great person is because not all great people are created equal, and some great people might be completely useless for you in a certain game (i.e. the great scientist which gives you bonus science for being next to natural wonders isn't any help at all when you first get it  if you haven't discovered any natural wonders).

Comment: You're saying that some great people are actually kind of mediocre?

Comment: @ZachLipton Essentially: yes.  They all have different bonuses, and you certainly might prefer one GP's bonus to another's.  E.g. consider that you're going for a science victory; the bonus you get from Stephanie Kwolek (+100% production on Space Race projects) is much better for you than other Great Scientists of that era, so you're better off passing until she shows up and then claiming her immediately.

Comment: A point of clarification, passing on a Great Person actually still deducts GPPs from your balance, just not anywheres near the total cost. I imagine this is so that it's less likely you'll be able to pass on it then change your mind the very next turn.

Comment: @raumkrieger once you pass, you are unable to recruit that person again even if you have enough points. You must wait until another player recruits them and the next person becomes available.

Comment: Also where do you see GPP?

Comment: @niico On the great person screen. You'll see your total for each under the slot for each great person type.

Comment: another thing to keep in mind is if you do pass, another civ has to hire that GP before you're offered another (as mao47 said). So if there's not another civ whose generating a lot of those GPP you might have to wait awhile before the next one becomes available.

Comment: This should be corrected to say that you **don't** keep all your GPP. (ideally, it could even include the exact amount of GPP you spend when passing)

Comment: My 2 cents, don't just consider whether that great person benefit you or not. Consider what would happen if  a great person is accepted by another civilisation. Sometimes it is a good idea to accept a great person  just to prevent a certain civ from accepting it.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing a lot of questionable answers...

Great people can be passed upon, it doesn't eat your points and you can either save for the next one (see the information below each GP) or you can spend money to get another one.

If you pass, you can still get said great person in a round or two.

I generally pass only when I see one coming soon that I really want. Aside that, I'll pile them up if I don't have space for their art or whatever until I build the correct district. But I looove tourism.

Comment: I hear about great person points - where can I see this figure?