# How can you sell great people?

Tags: civilization-6

In [Why would you not accept a free great person?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/293020/why-would-you-not-accept-a-free-great-person) we have a comment, twice stating:

> You can also sell a great person for decent money too.

I didn't know about that, where and how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can no longer sell units for gold. The commenter on that question is misinformed.

See "Balance Changes" section: https://civilization.com/news/entries/civilization-vi-fall-2016-update-now-live

> Deleting a unit no longer provides gold.